# Outlook app does not show PNG attachments in email messages sent through the API call

Tags: email, outlook, email-attachments

Apologies in advance for a rather abstract problem description.

I have an outlook mailbox to which I send a message with an attached PNG image through a built-in API call.

When the email arrives at to outlook mailbox (on web app or desktop app), I see no attachments.

If I send the same email with a PNG attached to my GMAIL account using the same API call, that email with the PNG attachment arrives as expected.

Could someone please advise why GMAIL and OUTLOOK mailboxes could behave differently? Could there be a problem with the API call or the server?

MIME

```
        Delivered-To: mtester@test.com
Received: by 2002:ac8:124d:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id g13csp604452qtj;
        Thu, 30 Sep 2021 06:30:46 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJzSSm54VUI64FiCNLMp63/T5SNi8pdUZMcX/nmZbGSLcew6JodBKWDkj1fUGv0YmUOQYDFA
X-Received: by 2002:aa7:8ecc:0:b0:434:d4fe:311b with SMTP id b12-20020aa78ecc000000b00434d4fe311bmr4582925pfr.22.1633008645701;
        Thu, 30 Sep 2021 06:30:45 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1633008645; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=MUVw5NvEuomZzBCy12ORQVZ+4WbYC4T8pWZkJYjomePfPsAcq42wKK1ceNZjuC5bgp
         GLNK3cgGk5eXk7N+wdTy7PN3qoEr0x4d/kmipkuI9v/mf1M86ht/Z2C9j+Bb8hOfR4D4
         +PTJs+5lBRWM9H571HDl4Cewa7Suc/krmjWnpw4pIDew3IbXEFkq80uVnyWHxQx6QC1l
         +K1h7NnyByCKp79WYsVz3Hlc2BNAYlGh+jNbwpA9ZPHCHRqNFvlmx75Vb+IdY5e4Nf4J
         Bs+S1i2RcxLELUU5+WSyzAX8vQY1oEZushVgIffIahQ9DN6m5AVVvClXSCyjaxBHy3Z0
         dB5g==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=list-id:list-unsubscribe:notification-stream-id:mime-version
         :subject:message-id:to:from:date:dkim-signature;
        bh=pFR40JQ2902/VixP+mqdG3A+OXkafDmmSdbRRZHIjrU=;
        b=U1jrKrN5u11bI9CxXg8eOSGALfm2Q2IsPt4HlBhSyIwwCQvTxD+f6zCBPXyyzhDdTQ
         d7tsb5boag+5hFXmi+VAbOvTbY34K+NvFKzHbuzRbWoCbPljwBaL02DCjVmsrgMvYaGu
         K4LjiSzpfyYP5Jf2IcPk5tIiijpeUMcItrmgv7Kx157/tyLyw3YYoBLbT2sBb1vPBJg3
         8APG/0FdaREtcLRqt22JivPTG/EATpUODR3m4qBB24ytEvHGcnmYS5r27xt03egAedfo
         0rxNL4Lhh+Tlv6nA9dQfKmzGaGkcc2Ux38jRS7FuWmbXqhLu1w1bIcIVEfe3ourr27oC
         JMgg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@development.test.com header.s=scph1119 header.b=aplxpcYW;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of msprvs1=18907xmukpyxm=bounces-21811-12061@spmailtechnol.com designates 192.174.90.181 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="msprvs1=18907xMUKpYxM=bounces-21811-12061@spmailtechnol.com";
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=development.test.com
Return-Path: <msprvs1=18907xMUKpYxM=bounces-21811-12061@spmailtechnol.com>
Received: from mta-90-181.sparkpostmail.com (mta-90-181.sparkpostmail.com. [192.174.90.181])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id x6si3536741pfb.329.2021.09.30.06.30.45
        for <mtester@test.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 30 Sep 2021 06:30:45 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of msprvs1=18907xmukpyxm=bounces-21811-12061@spmailtechnol.com designates 192.174.90.181 as permitted sender) client-ip=192.174.90.181;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@development.test.com header.s=scph1119 header.b=aplxpcYW;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of msprvs1=18907xmukpyxm=bounces-21811-12061@spmailtechnol.com designates 192.174.90.181 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="msprvs1=18907xMUKpYxM=bounces-21811-12061@spmailtechnol.com";
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=development.test.com
X-MSFBL: 71kOGDf9zf9xI2yo3tHvW/RTob2jTP/CmzLRto9+IBM=|eyJyIjoibWdlaWRyaWN oaXNAbnltYnVzLmNvbSIsInRlbmFudF9pZCI6InNwYyIsIm1lc3NhZ2VfaWQiOiI 2MTUxMDRiYzU1NjFkZDMwOWI4MiIsInN1YmFjY291bnRfaWQiOiIxMjA2MSIsImN 1c3RvbWVyX2lkIjoiMjE4MTEifQ==
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=development.test.com; s=scph1119; t=1633008645; i=@development.test.com; bh=pFR40JQ2902/VixP+mqdG3A+OXkafDmmSdbRRZHIjrU=; h=Date:From:To:Message-ID:Subject:Content-Type; b=aplxpcYWKZQDDNs2ie3UAJQRm43XWzz3+d2vCLU6/pvuE++Ho7IuVHjhkTT2Hfwca
     nIYG35q3O9NvorZFMF3YIOgEBnvkd4fFGq9yYWASRil57uFA+9JMMcIxFQX0FbZaw+
     9W9SVN8rdm2Aid7YQHSrlSphGljqsFDMARrpbv0I=
Authentication-Results: aa.mta1vlct.cc.prd.sparkpost smtp.user=<hidden>; auth=pass (LOGIN)
Received: from [64.106.167.126] ([64.106.167.126:34426] helo=mail-002.development.test.com) by aa.mta1vlct.cc.prd.sparkpost (envelope-from <dev40@development.test.com>) (ecelerity 4.4.0.17957 r(msys-ecelerity:tags/4.4.0.5)) with ESMTPSA (cipher=AES-256-GCM) id B9/28-33277-40CB5516; Thu, 30 Sep 2021 13:30:45 +0000
Received: from testing-868f87487d-nh4tt (worker03.testings01.development.test.com [10.0.204.190]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested) by mail-002.development.test.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id E21013AB for <mtester@test.com>; Thu, 30 Sep 2021 09:30:43 -0400 (EDT)
Date: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 09:30:43 -0400 (EDT)
From: dev40@development.test.com
To: mtester@test.com
Message-ID: <1302160953.5570.1633008643871@testing-868ff9787d-nh4tt>
Subject: test email from testhub
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847"
Notification-Stream-Id: EmailNotificationStream:1633008643484-0
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@unsub.spmta.com?subject=unsubscribe:CXvq00rTSMSrVDS7ikX5WwGZH1qnGJMttd8rMfKeGsw~|eyAicmNwdF90byI6ICJtZ2VpZHJpY2hpc0BueW1idXMuY29tIiwgInRlbmFudF9pZCI6ICJzcGMiLCAiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOiAiMjE4MTEiLCAibWVzc2FnZV9pZCI6ICI2MTUxMDRiYzU1NjFkZDMwOWI4MiIsICJzdWJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjogIjEyMDYxIiB9>
List-Id: <spc.21811.12061.sparkpostmail.com>

------=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_Part_5569_1922131613.1633008643847"

------=_Part_5569_1922131613.1633008643847
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body><h1>TEST html email from testhub controller</h1></body></html>
------=_Part_5569_1922131613.1633008643847
Content-Type: image/png; name="Capture 2.PNG"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Capture 2.PNG"
Content-ID: <Capture%202.PNG>


------=_Part_5569_1922131613.1633008643847--
------=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847--
```

Comment: You might want to post the MIME source of that email - you can see it in Gmail.

Comment: Thanks! here is the mime part of the original message. How could it help to investigate the problem? I'm quite new to this, sorry..

Comment: Is that the MIME source of the whole message? That looks like a single MIME header, not the whole message

Comment: oops, apologies. updated the message

Comment: Again, this is not a full MIME message, just a few incomplete headers. I am trying to see the MIME structure and all the MIME parts in relationship with each other.

Comment: Apologies again! I think i copy-pasted everything now

Answer (score 0):

The HTML body and the image are grouped into a multipart/related group, so Outlook probably hides the image attachment - this is usually done for the HTML images referenced by the body (which is not your case).

Try to get rid of that part:

```
...
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847"

------=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body><h1>TEST html email from testhub controller</h1></body></html>
------=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847
Content-Type: image/png; name="Capture 2.PNG"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Capture 2.PNG"
Content-ID: <Capture%202.PNG>

------=_Part_5568_1264138795.1633008643847--
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will investigate!